# Closing modal /popup box will not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot work out why, when I click 'x', the modal box/pop up will not close. It is completely unresponsive.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var kite = document.getElementById("poptext");
var kitetwo = document.getElementById("poptexttwo");
var closebtn = document.getElementById("close");

function seltst() {
  var kite = document.getElementById("poptext");
  var closebtn = document.getElementById("close");
  kite.style.display = 'block';
  setTimeout(el, 2000);
  kite.style.width = "500px";
}

function el() {
  kite.style.display = 'block';
}

function closepop() {
  kite.style.display = "none";
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<p>
  <input readonly type="text" value="a random value" id="tbox" onselect="seltst()">
</p>
<div id="poptextcont">
  <div id="poptext">
    <span id="close" onclick="closepop()">&times;</span>
    <p id="poptexttwo">
      lots of text about stuff<a href="aboutus.html">Contact us</a> more text!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answers only in pure JavaScript please.

Comment: why would you want to hide the `poptexttwo`  paragraph? shouldnt u hide the parent div? so the whole modal or dialog is no longer visible?

Comment: Pretty sure its because you do kite = document.getElementById("poptext"); before dom is loaded

Comment: your code is working. close button is actually closing popup

Comment: Dinesh, it will not close when I test it (Google Chrome). Juvian, that doesn't make any sense? The popup works as expected when I load it, however it will not CLOSE.

Comment: It makes much sense, as when you load it you are redeclaring kite, making it work for el function which is withing that scope. Anyway, @TheValyreanGroup answer should work

Comment: The code shown in the question works as is. I too suspect it's because the code is running before document ready (you define your vars before the dom nodes exist.)

Comment: It works in Google Chrome for me, in jsfidle.  However I think you should not declare a function in a function.

Comment: I cannot understand why it will not work for me then. I must have something conflicting elsewhere?

Comment: Most likely because you are defining those variables before the document has finished loading.

Comment: Damn. Must be, as it works once I moved the script to the bottom of the body.

Comment: Unobstrusive answer: https://jsfiddle.net/2djfkxzu/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of redundant code, after clean up this is what you got:

On click hide `poptext`, on select (highlight) show `poptext`

ALSO: make sure your script is just before `</body>` and must after all other html, in my example if you move the script above `p` will not work, why?

Because when page load you are calling `var kite = document.getElementById("poptext");` but the element is not loaded yet.

```html
<p>
  <input readonly type="text" value="a random value" id="tbox" onselect="seltst()">
</p>
<div id="poptextcont">
  <div id="poptext">
    <span id="close" onclick="closepop()">&times;</span>
    <p id="poptexttwo">
      lots of text about stuff<a href="aboutus.html">Contact us</a> more text!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var kite = document.getElementById("poptext");

  function seltst() {
    kite.style.display = 'block';
    kite.style.width = "500px";
  }

  function closepop() {
    kite.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

### But if you do this will work, you define kite inside the function, so when the function is called (the element already loaded):

```html
<script>
  function seltst() {
    var kite = document.getElementById("poptext");
    kite.style.display = 'block';
    kite.style.width = "500px";
  }

  function closepop() {
    var kite = document.getElementById("poptext");
    kite.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
<p>
  <input readonly type="text" value="a random value" id="tbox" onselect="seltst()">
</p>
<div id="poptextcont">
  <div id="poptext">
    <span id="close" onclick="closepop()">&times;</span>
    <p id="poptexttwo">
      lots of text about stuff<a href="aboutus.html">Contact us</a> more text!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I had actually moved the script to the end of the body (as I commented elsewhere) which worked, but extra kudos for cleaning up my code. It was a mess and now works and looks tidy.

and thanks for the excellent explanation!!

Comment: @Matt cool, just makes sure that the moment you running script the html are loaded. good luck

Answer (score -1):

Your `kite` variable is defined at the global scope, however not defined in the function you're trying to call.  Normally that would be fine, however, it seems it is declared before the DOM has loaded.

Redeclare that variable within the `closePop` function and you will be fine.

```
function closepop() {
   var kite = document.getElementById("poptext");
   kite.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It closes now, and I can't believe it was a simple as that. It does re-open once now though, but I'll have to debug to find out why. Thank you :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be correct; `kite` is defined on global scope in the very first line of the code in the question.  The code in the question doesn't throw any errors, in fact works just fine as is.

Comment: However much sense it makes, it rectified my problem. It simply will not close without doing as suggested above.

Comment: @DanielBeck it is not in the global scope.  It is inside the seltst() function which is only called when the textbox value is changed.

Comment: @Matt if this helped or answered your question please consider up voting and marking as the answer.

Comment: It is global. Look above the seltst() function

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup very first line of the code, as I said.

Comment: Ah.  I see that now and did not notice it before.  However, everyone else is likely correct.  That variable is declared before DOM load. Which is why my answer works.